# Python find maximum string length in the list of lists of lists

Tags: python, pandas, list

```
big_list = [[['asdf','ad'],['aqwe','rt']],['lkjyui','op'],['dfgh','hjk']]
```

Goal is to find the maximum string length in the whole big_list

My approach:

```
big_list = [[['asdf','ad'],['aqwe','rt']],['lkjyui','op'],['dfgh','hjk']]

listdf= pd.concat(pd.DataFrame(item).T for item in big_list ).reset_index(drop=True)
listdf = 
       0     1
0    asdf  aqwe
1      ad      
2  lkjyui    op
3    dfgh   hjk

print(listdf.astype(str).applymap(lambda x: len(x)).max().max())
6
```

Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Is this list already in a dataframe? If not, putting it in one might be as expensive as just doing the calculation in the first place. Are you going to use the dataframe for anything later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pandas:

```
out = listdf.stack().str.len().max()
```

In pure python:

```
out = max(len(x) for l in big_list for x in l)
```

Output: `6`

Comment: Wow! simply superb and one-line answer. I am curious when you say pure python way. does it mean, pandas' approach is not pure python? How do we know a specific solution among many is a pure pythonic approach? Thanks

Comment: I meant it as "without importing libraries" ;)

Comment: okay, now I know how to tell a pure python solution that does not import any special libraries. Thanks

Comment: If you have an `import` statement, it's likely using a library ;)

Answer (score 2):

If uisng pandas then

```
one = list(pandas.core.common.flatten(big_list))
print(len(max(one, key=len)))
```

give #

```
6
```